# Json mimetype in html

Tags: javascript, html, json, mime-types, mime

I have written a HTML/Javascript application to generate JSON Content. The structure is valid but the mimetype is stuck in default text/html. Can someone please advise how to set to application/json. My latest attempt is:

Blockquote

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/json; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Request JSON Test</title>
  </head>
 <body>
```

...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var jsonVar = {
    text: "example",
    number: 1
};
```

this way you can create java-script object and convert it into a string:

```
document.body.innerHTML = jsonStr;
```

this will show your object in json format.

Comment: this does not alter the mimetype. like my application, although the structure is valid JSON it will be interpretted as html/text

Comment: `var jsonVar = {
text: "example",
number: 1
};
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(jsonVar);
document.body.innerHTML = jsonStr;`